# how to get user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to press a Test Button and get what the user typed. When I click mine, I get "Test" instead of the number that I typed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#getNumber').click(function(event) {
    //alert(localStorage.getItem("maxnum"));
    alert($('#getNumber').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Give me Number:<input id="input1"><input id="getNumber" type="button" value="Test">
```

Comment: I think the `value` of the input you are selecting should be a clue

Comment: `alert($('#input1').val());`

Comment: BTW, having form inputs without names does not seem like a best practice ;)

Comment: input1 !== getNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because you used the wrong ID. `getNumber` is the button's ID and you need to use the `input`'s ID like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#getNumber').click(function(event) {
    alert(localStorage.getItem("maxnum"));
    alert($('#input1').val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse.. What you need is `alert( $('#input1').val())`

Answer (score -1):

change the html to this:

```
Give me Number:<input id="input1"><button id="getNumber" type="button">Test</button>
```